# How to replace all ul and li tag with div using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php, preg-match, simple-html-dom

Ok, I want to create a "website mobilizer" by using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. In the present phase, I want to-

1. change all 'ul' and 'li' tag to 'div' tag and
2. change all 'table' elements (e.g. table,tr,td,th) to div. I tried an workaround for the first problem in following way:

.

```
$html=new new simple_html_dom();
$html>load_file($sourceurl);

$div="div";
foreach ($html->find('ul') as $element) {  
 $element=$div;
 }
```

It does seem dull, but I'm not being able to find any other solution. I am discouraged for using `preg_match`, though I don't know if it can give me the desired output. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for using DOM parser instead of regex.

Comment: Is it at all possible to change a `ul` tag to a `div` tag using **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**? If yes, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible:

```
$html=new new simple_html_dom();
    $html>load_file($sourceurl);

    foreach ($html->find('ul') as $element) {  
     $element->innertext = "<div>".$element->innertext."</div>";     
    }
```

Of course you can do the same with table.
More in doucmetation: [Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Answer (score 3):

```
$html=new new simple_html_dom();
$html>load_file($sourceurl);

$replace="ul,li,table,tr,td,th";  
foreach($html->find($replace) as $key=>$element){
    $html->find($replace,$key)->outertext="<div>".$element->innertext."</div>"
}
```

this replaces all the elements from `$replace` array to `<div>` in `$html` DOM without changing the contents of those tags. Everything is stored in `$html` DOM.

As you can see you cant use `$element` to change anything in `$html`, even using `$element` as a reference, so you have to access `$html` directly.