# Replace first <p> tag using HTML DOM

Tags: php, dom

Q : As per task i need to replace `<p>` tag only for first occurrence with `h4` using `HTML DOM`.

I try it using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629289/how-to-replace-all-ul-and-li-tag-with-div-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser) but can't success

My code,

**HTML**

```
<div class="productabcont">
    <div class="protabtop">
        <div class="protabtopright">
            <p>Combed compact yarn</p> <!-- This i want to replace with <h4> tag. -->
            <p>Description line 1</p>
            <p>Description line 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php    
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($myHTML);
    $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')[0]->outertext = '<h4>'.$value.'</h4>';
    $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

**Required Output**

```
<div class="productabcont">
    <div class="protabtop">
        <div class="protabtopright">
            <h4>Combed compact yarn</h4> <!-- This is replaced with <p> tag. -->
            <p>Description line 1</p>
            <p>Description line 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's replaceWith() for DOM manipulation ?

Comment: Nop only want to do with `HTML DOM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `outerHTML` when using `DOM*` objects. But you can use all the other tools available.

For example:

```
<?php

$html = <<<HTML
<div class="productabcont">
    <div class="protabtop">
        <div class="protabtopright">
            <p>Combed compact yarn</p> <!-- This i want to replace with <h4> tag. -->
            <p>Description line 1</p>
            <p>Description line 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
HTML;

$value = 'some headline';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$q = new DOMXPath($dom);

// find first p tag
foreach ($q->query('//p[1]') as $p) {
    // replace it with newly created element
    $p->parentNode->replaceChild($dom->createElement('h4', $value), $p);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Sure you don't need to use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/class.domxpath.php) for such a simple example, but if you later need to be more explicit regarding which node needs to be replaced, it's easily extended.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/4Hj1e

Comment: But if only change only one occurrence no need to loop through `foreach`.
Just add `$q = new DOMXPath($dom);` `$p = $q->query('//p[1]');` `$p[0]->parentNode->replaceChild($dom->createElement('h4', $value), $p[0]);`.

Am i right  ?

Comment: @JaydeepMor That's correct, but then you'd need to check for whether there is a *found* element. The code would be equally verbose. That's why I tend to simply stick to the foreach when using `xpath->query`.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you can play with DOM by using the selectors and jQuery method.

Check this :[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjkk9vgz/)

```
var firstText = $(".protabtopright p:first").text();
$(".protabtopright p:first").replaceWith("<h4>" + firstText + "</h4>");
```